# Processing buffer in javascript with graceful shutdown

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

My team has been doing some refactoring in an app and we needed to add a buffer to our data pipeline processing. We are working with node.js and javascript.

Specifically, there is an event emitter that can emit many events per second. In our design, we place these events into a buffer, and every x seconds we try to flush this buffer, where flushing means running the events through the pipeline. Running this pipeline takes some time, and we can only run one pipeline at any time. We have some unit tests and got our code to work, but the solution feels hacky. The main classes are posted below:

`TxBuffer.js`

```javascript
export default class TxBuffer {
  constructor() {
    this.q = Array();
  }

  size() {
    return this.q.length;
  }

  push(elt) {
    this.q.push(elt);
  }

  popAll() {
    const all = this.q.slice();
    this.q = Array();
    return all;
  }
}
```

`BufferedExecutor.js`

```js
import { mustBe } from "../paramChecker/paramChecker.js";
import { setInterval, setTimeout } from "timers/promises";

export default class BufferedExecutor {
  constructor(buffer, pipeline, { flushTimeout = 100 }) {
    this.buffer = buffer;
    this.pipeline = pipeline;
    this.flushTimeout = flushTimeout;
    this.running = false;
    this.finished = false;
  }

  async start() {
    this.running = true;
    while (this.running) {
      await this.flush();
      await setTimeout(this.flushTimeout);
    }

    await this.flush();
    this.finished = true;
  }

  async flush() {
    const txs = this.buffer.popAll();
    if (txs.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    const txRes = await this.pipeline.runMany(txs);
  };

  async stop() {
    this.running = false;
    const checksPerInterval = 10;

    // This creates an iterable of asyncs that is traversed with this for loop
    for await (const _ of setInterval(this.flushTimeout / checksPerInterval)) {
      if (this.finished) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The way this is put together in main is something like this (this code is untested):

```js
async function main() {
  const pipeline = {
    runMany: async () => {
      return await setTimeout(3000);
    }
  };

  const txBuffer = new TxBuffer();
  const bufferExecutor = new BufferedExecutor(txBuffer, pipeline, { flushTimeout: 5000 });
  
  bufferExecutor.start();

  // Somewhere else in main, we place things in the buffer
  // eventEmitter.on("event", (evt) => {
  //  txBuffer.push(evt);
  // })
  
  await bufferExecutor.stop();
}
```

We are concerned about a couple of things:

1. Is the implementation of `BufferedExecutor` correct? Does it have any subtle issues? How does this work with locks.
2. The `this.running` and `this.finished` flags in `BufferedExecutor` feel hacky. Is there a better way to solve this problem of signaling for shutdown?

Thank you for all the help in advance, and let me know if more info is needed.